# ESP8266 as Client and AJAX web sever

Tags: html, ajax, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I would like to run ESP8266 as a client which will be controlled by the server which will run on my computer. I would like the server to send commands to ESP8266 with a use of AJAX and the ESP8266 will respond to them and will be able to send as well to the server which will run on my computer.
Is there any example of code that I'll be able to use please? Can someone help me with an example of code in order to let me know how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: There's a lot of sample code for these guys-try that then come back with specific questions. As it is this is OT for a variety of reasons.

Comment: I didn't find any example of code that does what I mentioned. If you have one please send me and I'll see.

Comment: It's running the ESP as a server; that code is out there. http://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp8266-web-server/, https://learn.adafruit.com/esp8266-temperature-slash-humidity-webserver/overview, whatever. Search. Top five results for me are all what you're asking for. Sending out is the same.

Comment: Did you read before? I would like to run the ESP8266 as a client not as a server, I want to run the server on my computer.

Comment: Then how will you be sending commands to it? You explicitly said you'd send commands to the ESP with Ajax. Did *you* read before?! Good grief. Good luck. There are tons of examples for both sending and receiving data. When you have a specific question feel free to try again, although I might suggest the embedded stack exchange.

Comment: I'll send commands to it with a use of AJAX of course but the the server which will send the AJAX commands will be on my computer and the esp which will get the AJAX data will work as a client which will be connected to the server....

Comment: If you're making Ajax requests to the ESP then the ESP is acting as a server for that part ¯\(°_o)/¯

Answer (score 0):

You can find a whole lot about ESP 8266 in client mode. It's not very much different from when it is in server mode. You have to long poll the AJAX server so that you can ever get updates (or you need to use some other way of communication, like websockets, but I don't think you are interested in it).

Here is one example:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uznq8W9sOKQ

Here is another one:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z07zjfOHb8E

Here is another one (this one from Kevin Darrah is my favorite, explains all concepts far better than the previous two):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qU76yWHeQuw

Here is the part 2 of the last one:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zGgUfAB4m24

Because AJAX supports only one way communication (i.e. only client can send requests to the server and not the other way around), your client, aka ESP 8266, will have to query for its current state. In other words, it will be something like:

```
ESP8266: Anything new?
Server: No.
ESP8266: Anything new?
Server: No.
ESP8266: Anything new?
Server: No.
ESP8266: Anything new?
Server: No.
ESP8266: Anything new?
Server: No.
ESP8266: Anything new?
Server: No.
ESP8266: Anything new?
Server: No.
ESP8266: Anything new?
Server: Yes. Toggle the LED On.
ESP8266: OK. Anything new?
Server: No.
ESP8266: Anything new?
Server: No.
ESP8266: Anything new?
Server: No.
ESP8266: Anything new?
Server: No.
ESP8266: Anything new?
Server: No.
ESP8266: Anything new?
Server: Yes. Toggle the LED off.
ESP8266: OK. Anything new?
Server: No.
```

and so on.